# How to create a console app that references Xamarin.Mac.dll in .NET 6

Tags: xamarin.mac, .net-6.0

[This guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/mac/app-fundamentals/console) explains how to create a console app that uses Xamarin.Mac APIs. The trick is to reference `Xamarin.Mac.dll` and link `libxammac.dylib` in your project. But it is limited to the Mono runtime (pre-.NET-Core).

With .NET 6, there are now [workloads](https://github.com/dotnet/designs/blob/main/accepted/2020/workloads/workloads.md) and a new `net6.0-macos` target runtime. However, this seems to assume that you are creating a GUI app rather than a console app.

When installing the workload in .NET 6, it seems to only install a reference assembly for `Xamarin.Mac.dll`. So where is the real `Xamarin.Mac.dll` for .NET 6? And is it possible to use it without targeting `net6.0-macos`?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get a console app to run following [this example](https://github.com/chucker/net6-mac-console-sample).

The main point is that `.csproj` needs to contain:

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-macos</TargetFramework>
    <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>osx-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

And there needs to be an `info.plist` file in the project directory.

It isn't quite what I was hoping for since it still creates a `.app` bundle and `dotnet run` doesn't actually run the app. You have to manually run `bin/Debug/net6.0-macos/osx-x64/MyProject.app/Contents/MacOS/MyProject`.

---

Answering the question about where the real `Xamarin.Mac.dll` and associated native libraries live: it appears to be in the [Microsoft.macOS.Runtime.osx-x64](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.macOS.Runtime.osx-x64/) NuGet package. However, this isn't a normal package that can be referenced from a project.